# access only parent node attribute without having children

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, nodes

I have an XML file and want to extract some nodes of it in a new XML file and save it. The XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files version="2.1.8" Dir="D:Test\Exm_2" modified="2016-03-18 23:14:58Z" user="Test" language="en">
    <file name="1">
        <file name="4">
           <file name="9">
           </file>
        </file> 
    </file>
    <file name="2">
    </file>
    <test name="3">
        <test name="5">
            <test name="7">
            </test>
        </test>
    </test>
</files>
```

My aim is that to save some special nodes(here test nodes) of this XML file. The idea is to save the root attribute attached with it as well. I mean if I want to save nodes `test` in a new file I want to have the root attribute as the original XML file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files version="2.1.8" Dir="D:Test\Exm_2" modified="2016-03-18 23:14:58Z" user="Test" language="en"> 
    <tests>       
        <test name="3">
            <test name="5">
                <test name="7">
                </test>
            </test>
        </test>
    </tests>
</files>
```

But I failed to save its attribute. My code for saving the second XML file is

```
public void Creat_Steps(string xmlfile, string FileName)
{
    XElement doc = XElement.Load(xmlfile);
    var item = doc.XPathSelectElement("//test");
    XElement newDoc = new XElement("files", new XElement("tests", item));
    XElement Docc = new XElement("files", item);

    Docc.Save(FileName + ".xml");
}
```

But this code create only a root node with name `files` without any attribute. I have to use the attribute in the new XML file and then have not it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix your sample XML - it's currently invalid as you don't have enough end-file elements. It's not clear whether that's because `<file name="4">` should be `<file name="4" />` or whether name 9 should be within name 4, but it's easier to help you if the XML is valid to start with. We shouldn't need to fix it up ourselves to test.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would just be to replace the child nodes of the root element instead:

```
var root = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
root.ReplaceNodes(new XElement("tests", root.Elements("test")));
root.Save(FileName + ".xml");
```

Note that there's no need for XPath here either :) Also note that I'm using `Elements` rather than `Descendants`, otherwise each `test` element will become a new immediate child of `tests`, which isn't what you want.

I'd personally suggest using `XDocument` to load and save documents, as that clearly states your intent, btw. At that point you'd use

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(...);
doc.Save(...);
```